# Finding the length of the chord of contact of the parabola.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

> Tangents are drawn to the parabola $y^2= 4x$ from the point $(1,3)$
>   What is the length of the chord of contact?

The chord of contact is $3y-2x-2=0$

The points of intersection of this chord with the parabola are : $(\dfrac{7 \pm \sqrt{45}}{2},\dfrac{6 \pm \sqrt{20}}{2})$

Using distance formula I get the length to be $\dfrac{\sqrt{65}}{2}$ but answer given is $\sqrt{65}.$ Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: The difference between the $x$-coordinates is $\sqrt{45}$ and the difference between the $y$-coordinates is $\sqrt{20}$, so the distance is $\sqrt{65}$. Double-check your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the correct coordinates, but if you check the distance formula the answer is indeed $\sqrt{65}$ not $\frac 12\sqrt{65}$

Answer (score 1):

The length of any chord in a parabola is given as:

$$\frac{4}{m^2}\sqrt{a(1+m^2)(a-mc)}$$

where m is the slope of the chord whose length is to be calculated and $c$ is the constant $t$ of that chord.

Comment: The formulae is working but you should edit your answer as it is very confusing.